# Saving an NSView to a png file?

Tags: objective-c, nsview, nssavepanel

I am making a simple program that creates game cards for a game I play. I have sent it out to some friends of mine for testing, but they really want it to save images, not just print them. I have tried to make it save as a .png file. I have to questions here.

- How can I make it save my view as a .png file, including all of the view's NSImageWells.
- How can I add an NSPopupButton to an NSSavePanel to allow users to select a format?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First create a TIFF representation of your view:

```
// Get the data into a bitmap.
[self lockFocus];
rep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithFocusedViewRect:[self bounds]];
[self unlockFocus];
data = [rep TIFFRepresentation];
```

To support multiple file types, use:

```
data = [rep representationUsingType:(NSBitmapImageFileType)storageType
properties:(NSDictionary *)properties];
```

NSBitmapImageFileType is an enum constant specifying a file type for bitmap images. It can be NSBMPFileType, NSGIFFileType, NSJPEGFileType, NSPNGFileType, or NSTIFFFileType.

If you need to customize the NSSavePanel, look into accessory views: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AppFileMgmt/Articles/ManagingAccessoryViews.html

Comment: Edit: whoops, re-read it. Didn't realize you've already covered that. Will remove it in a few.

Comment: -[NSData writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag] will be of interest.

Comment: Ok. I got it to work by adding this code:[data writeToFile:[savePanel filename] atomically:YES];. The idea came from this [this](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/04/05/download-an-image-and-save-it-as-png-or-jpeg-in-iphone-sdk/) website.

Answer (score 4):

```
// Get the data into a bitmap.
[viewBarChart lockFocus];
NSBitmapImageRep *rep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithFocusedViewRect:[viewBarChart bounds]];
[viewBarChart unlockFocus];
NSData *exportedData = [rep representationUsingType:NSJPEGFileType properties:nil];

NSSavePanel *savepanel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
savepanel.title = @"Save chart";

[savepanel setAllowedFileTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"jpg"]];

[savepanel beginSheetModalForWindow:self.view.window completionHandler:^(NSInteger result)
 {
     if (NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton == result)
     {
         NSURL* fileURL = [savepanel URL];

         if ([fileURL.pathExtension isEqualToString:@""])
             fileURL = [fileURL URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"jpg"];

         [exportedData writeToURL:fileURL atomically:YES];
     }

     [rep release];
 }];
```