# How to save a NSImage in Mac OSX with subviews?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, nsimage

I have the current code that's working for ios.But as many of you know UIKit isn't in Mac OSX apps.How could I save a nsimage with the subviews I added

```
private func screenShotMethod() -> NSImage? {

    //Create the UIImage
    NSGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.pickedImge.frame.size)
    self.pickedImge.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = NSGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    NSGraphicsEndImageContext()

    //Save it to the camera roll
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image!, nil, nil, nil)
    return image!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've ported this answer from code I found in [this very related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491403/saving-an-nsview-to-a-png-file).

```
class CustomView : NSView {

    func saveAScreenShotOfThisViewSomewhere() -> Void {
        self.lockFocus()
        let rep = NSBitmapImageRep(focusedViewRect: self.bounds)
        self.unlockFocus()
        if let data = rep?.tiffRepresentation {
            do {
                try data.write(to: URL(string:"/tmp/someplace.tiff")!, options: Data.WritingOptions.atomic)
            } catch {
                Swift.print("error in writing -> \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use

```
    if let data = rep?.representation(using: .JPEG, properties: [String : Any]) {

    }
```

where representation includes BMP, GIF, JPEG, PNG, TIFF, etc.

I hope this helps!

Comment: That's great but i'm using a NSImage not a NSView.The function above is taking a screenshot of a UIImage with the subviews

Comment: You can also use the code above to subclass `NSImageView` so you can save both the image contained by the image view as well as its subclasses.  Did I misunderstand your question?